# Converting from java ArrayList obtained from unwrapped() to Scala list

Tags: java, scala, configuration, config, configuration-files

Lang : SCALA 
I have one `map` defined in my properties files as:

```
dummy {
  "Key1" : ["value1","value2", "value3"]
  "Key2" : ["Hi1", "Hi2"]
  "Key3" : ["Bye1"]
}
```

Now, I could find `entryset` for above `map` and fill it in scala's `map` as:

```
var configTrialMap: Config = config.getConfig("dummy")
val resMap = mutable.Map[String, List[String]]()
for (entry <- configTrialMap.entrySet.asScala) {
    resMap.put(entry.getKey, entry.getValue.unwrapped().toString.split(",").map(_.trim).toList)
}
```

But problem is this code looks clumsy and I have to put some regex to replace all `[, ]` with blank character

I have seen some solutions to convert java collection to scala one but none of them seem to be working since `unwrapped()` return an `Object` instance and I have to cast it first.

I have tried playing with:

1. `asScalaBuffer` (https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-go-from-java-collections-convert-in-scala-interact)
2. `val javaToScalaList = entry.getValue.unwrapped().asInstanceOf[List[String]]`
3. `.asScala.toList`

Sorry, if it is too naive. I am new to scala.

Comment: If `configTrialMap` is a java map (let's say a `java.util.HashMap`), then you can simply get the Scala map by `configTrialMap.asScala`

Comment: @jrook No its not a java map. It is a config object. I might not understood what you meant? Can you please elaborate with exact what changes you are asking for...

Comment: Could you please add detail about the *Config* class? What is its fully qualified name? (the name including the whole path to the class). Since you stated it was a `map`, I assumed it might be a `java.util.HashMap`. If that is not correct, then what kind of map is it?

Comment: It is `com.typesafe.config.Config` . When I said it is a map, I meant map defined in config file( a virtual map which I want to convert to actual scala map) Hope it helps @jrook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
  import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
  //load config into configTrialMap

configTrialMap.getObject("dummy")
  .keySet().asScala
  .map(k => {
    val k2 = k.replaceAll("\\.", "\".\"")  //quote all the dots in key
    ("dummy."+k2, configTrialMap.getStringList(s"dummy." + k2).asScala.toList)
  })
  .toMap
```

which results in:

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[String]] = Map(dummy.U"."S"." Sample -> List(Bye1), dummy.Key2 -> List(Hi1, Hi2), dummy.Key1 -> List(value1, value2, value3))
```

**EDIT:** (to add regex replacement to fix paths with dots)

To handle dots in keys, you need to quote them using `"` character. I have updated the answer with a regex that does this.

Comment: Perfect Sir :) I am able to use your logic successfully and tweaked it also to create Map of `Map[String, String]` accordingly as per some other requirement. Thanks again

Comment: if key is like  "U.S. Sample" then it fails, any workaround? - I tried to put in quotes, wrapped under object - but none of them worked . Also tried `U"""."""S"""."""` and escaped quotes while making map and using `getString()` method but no luck so far

Comment: Thanks brother, I will try it out soon, left for home now :)

Comment: It works but then when I have some "runtime random value" and want to find it in map's `keyset()` then first I have to use same regex for that "runtime random value". Kind of hack but not clean, any other suggestions?

Comment: @JeetendraAhuja, that's another problem, which is easily solvable with something like `finalConfigTrial.map {case (k,v) => (k.replace(""""""",""), v)}`.

Comment: Yes, I thought of it too but was wondering for any other non-regex solution. NP Sir, I will go with it now and will think of something else if possible. Thanks for all help.

Comment: @JeetendraAhuja as long as `.` can have two meanings (path separator and a character in config file), you have to escape it no matter what technique you use.

Comment: Yes, I understand it. Thanks.